# Recognize direction of hammerjs pinch gesture and the degree of zoom

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

Is there a way to recognize [hammerjs pinch](http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-pinch/) if the direction is inward or downward and to the degree of zoom or how much is it zoomed in or out? I'm quite new to this technology and I find it hard to check the event object through log because I'm testing in a mobile app.